# Should Xamarin questions also use xaml or c# tags?

Tags: discussion

I'm a bit active in the Xamarin tag (mainly xamarin.forms tag) and I read everyday questions about Xamarin. These questions are mainly:

1. Questions about the UI
2. Questions about the code behind / functionality

The first type of questions rarely have the **XAML** tag and the *language* to create the UI in a Xamarin app is XAML. So, in my opinion they should include this tag.

The second type of questions usually don't have the **C#** tag, however in the majority of the cases the problem is related to C#. C# is also the language used to write the code for Xamarin apps.

In summary I think that questions about Xamarin UI have to use the XAML tag and questions about Xamarin code have to use the C# tag. This also could improve the visibility of these questions.

There are some meta discussions that support my opinion [Language tags on library questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250876/language-tags-on-library-questions?rq=1), [Should processing questions also be tagged with java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251014/should-processing-questions-also-be-tagged-with-java).

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the vast majority of Silverlight, WPF, WinRT and UWP questions all include the [xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xaml) tag, I don't see why Xamarin should be any different.

I don't see any problem with including the programming language either, if the question is about writing code (be it code-behind or application logic). The aforementioned technologies support a variety of languages besides C#, and language tags are relevant wherever code plays a primary role.